# How can i make arraylist from loop of method

Tags: android, arraylist

Hi i am a newbie in android actually in coding not just android.. so i am trying to develop app that display multiplication table start from 1 x 1 to undefine.. is there a way to create this with simple coding using listview instead of making 10 textview  each table.. i have been able to make listview with viewpager but i have to define string array for each table.. so i create many string array..  i need your assistance guys..

This is string that i made

```
String[] table1 = {"1 x 1 = 1", "1 x 2 = 2", ...}
String[] table2 = {"2 x 1 = 2", "2 x 2 = 4", ...}
String[] table3 ...
...
```

Can we create this with loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call below function when you when and which table you want like this.

```
MakeTable(1);
```

if you pass 1, it will make table of 1, if pass 2 it will make table of 2.

```
public void MakeTable(int a){

      int b = 0, ans = 0;
        String[] mul = new String[10];


            for(int j=1;j<=10;j++){


                b = j;
                ans = a * b;

                mul[j-1] = a +" * "+b +" = " +ans;

                Log.e("== > ","== "+mul[j-1]);
                if(j == 10){

                    list.add(mul);

                }

            }


    }
```

if you want to add table using button.

```
int x = 1;
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

             MakeTable(x);
             x++;
            }
        });
```

Comment: now i confuse to populate listView from those array.. i tried but result empty listview..pls advise

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String[]> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String[]>(getContext(), R.layout.row_textview,R.id.rowText,list);

Comment: Use Custom list view to display table data.

Comment: i remove the array list change it to undefine public string array.. and i define it on the makeTable method instead of list.add(mul) and it works.. is this acceptable

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
int a = 0, b = 0, ans = 0;
String[] mul = new String[10];

for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){


    for(int j=1;j<=10;j++){

        a = i;
        b = j;
        ans = a * b;

        mul[j-1] = a +" * "+b +" = " +ans;

       Log.e("== > ","== "+mul[j-1]);
        if(j == 10){

            list.add(mul);

        }

    }

    if(i == 100){

        **Log.e("List ","  = "+list);**
    }

}
```

Comment: feel free to ask for any confusion.

Comment: Hi thx.. it really bright me more about coding.. i still wondering is this going to display all the table at once.. how can we stop the loop after 1 string array being add.. we control by button for example